# Modifying struct data in a ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I have a struct that outlines the data, and then a class that has an array of the structs.

```
struct Example: Codable, Identifiable {
     var id: UUID

     var title: String
     var description: String?

     var tags: [String]
}

class Examples: ObservableObject {
     @Published var examples = [Example]()
}
```

Then, I have a ForEach that displays the data with a button:

```
ForEach(examples.examples) { example in
     VStack {
         Button("Complete") {
            example.completed = true
         }
         Text(example.title)
     }
}
```

When I try to run, it gives me the error "Cannot assign to property: 'example' is a 'let' constant." I've tried passing the example into a separate view with an @Binding var (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997248/how-to-edit-an-item-in-a-list-using-navigationlink) ) and also modifying the data with an index (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536774/swiftui-changing-struct-data-set-in-foreach)), but both give me an error saying that Xcode was unable to produce a diagnostic report and to file feedback. How can I modify the data?

Sorry if this is a bad question, I'm pretty new to SwiftUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because a ForEach returns you a read-only *copy* of the original `example` to operate on and you can't modify it. And even if you could it wouldn't be the same struct (structs are value types).

You need to access the original item instead:

```
var body: some View {
    ForEach(examples.examples.indices) { index in
        VStack {
            Button("Complete") {
                examples.examples[index].completed = true
            }
            Text(examples.examples[index].title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this approach does not work if you want to be able to reorder/delete/insert items in the examples array. Any ideas for that case? The items in the ForEach would need to be identified by the id property rather than by index.

Comment: @Anton you could enumerate over the data ForEach(Array(examples.enumerated), id: \.element) { index, element in ... }

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Example: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var tags: [String]
    var completed = false
}

class Examples: ObservableObject {
    @Published var examples : [Example]
    
    init() {
        self.examples = [Example(title: "Title 1", description: "Desc 1", tags: ["tag 1", "tag 1.1", "tag 1.2"]),
                         Example(title: "Title 2", description: "Desc 2", tags: ["tag 2"]),
                         Example(title: "Title 3", description: "Desc 3", tags: ["tag 3", "tag 3.1"])
        ]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var examples = Examples()
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($examples.examples) { $example in
            VStack {
                Button("Complete") {
                    example.completed.toggle()
                }
                Text(example.title + " " + example.completed.description)
                TextField("Description", text: $example.description)
                    
                ForEach($example.tags, id: \.self) { $t in
                    TextField("Tag ", text: $t)
                }
            }
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
}
```