# Accessing and manipulating array item in an EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment

I have an `EnvironmentObject` that I'm using to generate a list

```
class ActivityViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var Activities = [Activity]()
    
    init() {
        self.Activities = ActivityService.fetchActivities()
    }
}

struct Activity: Codable {
    var Id: UUID
    var Name: String
    var Records: [Record]
    
    init(Name:String) {
        self.Id = UUID.init()
        self.Name = Name
        self.Records = [Record]()
    }
}
```

When I'm using this in the view, I can use a `ForEach` to access each value in the `Activities` array.

My issue is when I use a NavigationLink to pass this `Activity` to another view, it's not then using the `EnvironmentObject`

My 'parent view' code:

```
ForEach(0..<activities.Activities.count, id: \.self) { activity in
    HStack {
        ActivityListItemView(activity: self.activities.Activities[activity])
    }
}
```

My child view code:

```
struct ActivityListItemView: View {
    let activity: Activity
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ActivityDetail(Activity: activity)) {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text(activity.Name)
                        Text("\(activity.Records.count) records")
                    }
                }
                
                Text(">")
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

If I then update the viewModel, I need this to replicate into the child view. But I can't figure out how to make it use the `EnvironmentObject`, rather than just the variable I pass to the view.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Added activity type

Comment: What is `Activity` type?

Comment: Off topic but property names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Just edited to add Activity.

Comment: You need to use Binding to element of published array (because element is value, so copied if passed directly). See example of scenario in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001742/12299030.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is similar to Apple's in this tutorials.

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

---

Confirm to `Identifiable`  and  `Equatable`.

```
   struct Activity: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
       var id: UUID
       var name: String
   //    var Records: [Record]
       
       init(Name:String) {
           self.id = UUID()
           self.name = Name
   //        self.Records = [Record]()
       }
   }
```

Iterate over `activity.activities` and pass your `view-model` and `activity` to `ActivityListItemView`

```
   ForEach(viewModel.activities) { activity in
     HStack {
         ActivityListItemView(viewModel: viewModel, activity: activity)
     }
 }
```

In `ActivityListItemView`, find index of its activity

```
private var activityIndex: Int? {
     viewModel.activities.firstIndex(of: activity)
  }
```

Unwrap `activityIndex` and pass `$viewModel.activities[index]` to `ActivityDetail`

```
var body: some View {
      if let index = activityIndex {
          NavigationLink(destination: ActivityDetail(activity: $viewModel.activities[index])) {
              ...
          }
          ...
      }
  }
```

Use `@Binding` wrapper in `ActivityDetail`.

```
    struct ActivityDetail: View {
        @Binding var activity: Activity
        
        var body: some View {
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

A complete working exammple.

```
class ActivityViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var activities = [Activity]()
    
    init() {
        self.activities = [Activity(Name: "A"), Activity(Name: "B"), Activity(Name: "C"), Activity(Name: "D"), Activity(Name: "E")]
    }
}

struct Activity: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
//    var Records: [Record]
    
    init(Name:String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = Name
//        self.Records = [Record]()
    }
}


struct ActivityView: View {
   @ObservedObject  var viewModel = ActivityViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.viewModel.activities.append(Activity(Name: "\(Date())"))
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
        ForEach(viewModel.activities) { activity in
            HStack {
                ActivityListItemView(viewModel: viewModel, activity: activity)
            }
        }

    }
}


struct ActivityListItemView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ActivityViewModel
    
    let activity: Activity
    
    private var activityIndex: Int? {
        viewModel.activities.firstIndex(of: activity)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let index = activityIndex {
            NavigationLink(destination: ActivityDetail(activity: $viewModel.activities[index])) {
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text(activity.name)
    //                        Text("\(activity.Records.count) records")
                        }
                    }
                    Text(">")
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}


struct ActivityDetail: View {
    @Binding var activity: Activity
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(activity.name)")
    }
}
```