# SwiftUI - ForEach deletion transition always applied to last item only

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I'm trying to add a delete animation to my `ForEach`, so that each `Card` inside it scales out when removed. This is what I have so far:

[image]

The problem is that no matter which `Card` is pressed, it's **always the last one that animates**. And sometimes, the text inside each card has a weird sliding/morphing animation. Here's my code:

```
/// Ran into this problem: "SwiftUI ForEach index out of range error when removing row"
/// `ObservableObject` solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62796050/14351818
class Card: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cards = [
        Card(name: "Apple"),
        Card(name: "Banana "),
        Card(name: "Coupon"),
        Card(name: "Dog"),
        Card(name: "Eat")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                
                ForEach(cards.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    CardView(card: cards[index], removePressed: {
                        
                        withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                            _ = cards.remove(at: index) /// remove the card
                        }
                        
                    })
                    .transition(.scale)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var card: Card
    var removePressed: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            removePressed?() /// call the remove closure
        }) {
            VStack {
                Text("Remove")
                Text(card.name)
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
        .padding(40)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

How can I scale out the `Card` that is clicked, and not the last one?

Comment: You need to make sure that your `id`s actually identify the object being deleted. Right now your `id`s that `ForEach` is using are just indices - an `Int`, in this case. So when you delete an item and the view re-renders, the only difference in the array is that the last id is gone.

Comment: @NewDev thanks, makes sense! How would you suggest I id them? Would something like `cards.map { $0.id }` be good?

Comment: Nvm, that results in "Cannot convert value of type '[UUID]' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<Range<Array<Card>.Index>.Element, ID>'"

Comment: Why are you doing `ForEach` over indices here? I think you can do `ForEach(cards) { card in ...}` since each `Card` is `Identifiable`

Comment: @NewDev the indices were so that I could do `cards.remove(at: index)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is because you use an index as an `id` for `ForEach`. So, when an element is removed from the `cards` array, the only difference that `ForEach` sees is that the last index is gone.

You need to make sure that the `id` uniquely identifies each element of `ForEach`.

If you must use indices and have each element identified, you can either use the `enumerated` method or `zip` the array and its indices together. I like the latter:

```
ForEach(Array(zip(cards.indices, cards)), id: \.1) { (index, card) in 
   //...
}
```

The above uses the object itself as the `ID`, which requires conformance to `Hashable`. If you don't want that, you can use the `id` property directly:

```
ForEach(Array(zip(cards.indices, cards)), id: \.1.id) { (index, card) in
  //...
}
```

---

For completeness, here's the `enumerated` version (technically, it's not an index, but rather an offset, but for 0-based arrays it's the same):

```
ForEach(Array(cards.enumerated()), id: \.1) { (index, card) in 
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However I also get `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Card' conform to 'Hashable'` with both of the above examples. Why would this happen?

Comment: Btw once I conform to `Hashable`, it works perfectly.

Comment: However this breaks `proxy.scrollTo(cards.count - 1, anchor: .center)` when inside a `ScrollViewReader { proxy in`. I think it might be because of the `id: \.1` - could you explain what that is for?

Comment: Your first senetance is false. Aheze does not use index as id.

Comment: @aheze, `id: \.1` uses the second element from a `(index, card)` tuple - which is a `Card` - as an `id`, but you're right - it needs to conform to `Hashable`. If you don't want that, you can use the `id` property directly with `id: \.1.id` (I updated the answer)

Comment: @mahan, why do you think it's wrong? In the original question, he's using `ForEach(cards.indices, id: \.self) { }`, i.e. iterating over an array of indices, and `id: \.self` referring to each element - an index - as the id.

Answer (score 1):

[New Dev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66944424/14351818) was great, but I had something else that I needed. In my full code, I had a button inside each `Card` that scrolled the `ScrollView` to the end.

```
/// the ForEach
ForEach(Array(cards.enumerated()), id: \.1) { (index, card) in
    CardView(
        card: cards[index],
        scrollToEndPressed: {
            proxy.scrollTo(cards.count - 1, anchor: .center) /// trying to scroll to end... not working though.
        },
        removePressed: {
            
            withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                _ = cards.remove(at: index) /// remove the card
            }
            
        }
    )
    .transition(.scale)
}

/// CardView
struct CardView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var card: Card
    var scrollToEndPressed: (() -> Void)?
    var removePressed: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                scrollToEndPressed?() /// scroll to the end
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Scroll to end")
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                removePressed?() /// call the remove closure
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Remove")
                    Text(card.name)
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
            .padding(40)
            .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, the "Scroll to end" button didn't work.

[image: "Scroll to end" above each Card, but clicking it doesn't work]

I fixed this by assigning an explicit `ID` to each `CardView`.

```
ForEach(Array(cards.enumerated()), id: \.1) { (index, card) in
    CardView(card: cards[index], scrollToEndPressed: {
        
        withAnimation(.easeOut) { /// also animate it
            proxy.scrollTo(cards.last?.id ?? card.id, anchor: .center) /// scroll to the last card's ID
        }
        
    }, removePressed: {
        
        withAnimation(.easeOut) {
            _ = cards.remove(at: index) /// remove the card
        }

    })
    .id(card.id) /// add ID
    .transition(.scale)
}
```

Result:

[image: "Scroll to end" above each Card works!]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to rethink and use Card as **struct** rather than a **class** and confirm to **Identifiable** and  **Equatable**.

```
struct Card: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And then create a View Model that holds your cards.

```
class CardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var cards: [Card] = [
        Card(name: "Apple"),
        Card(name: "Banana "),
        Card(name: "Coupon"),
        Card(name: "Dog"),
        Card(name: "Eat")
    ]
}
```

---

Iterate over `cardViewModel.cards` and pass `card` to the `CardView`. Use `removeAll` method of Array instead of `remove`. It is safe since `Card`s are unique.

```
ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
   CardView(card: card) {
        withAnimation(.easeOut) {
          cardViewModel.cards.removeAll { $0 == card}
       }
   }       
}
```

---

A complete working exammple.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cardViewModel = CardViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                
                ForEach(cardViewModel.cards) { card in
                    CardView(card: card) {
                        withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                            cardViewModel.cards.removeAll { $0 == card}
                        }
                    }
                    .transition(.scale)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
        
    var card: Card
    
    var removePressed: (() -> Void)?

    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            removePressed?()
        }) {
            VStack {
                Text("Remove")
                Text(card.name)
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
        .padding(40)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

---

If for some reason you need index of card in `ContentView`, do this.

1. [Accessing and manipulating array item in an EnvironmentObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653246/accessing-and-manipulating-array-item-in-an-environmentobject/65655965#65655965)
2. [Removing items from a child view generated by For Each loop causes Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045734/removing-items-from-a-child-view-generated-by-for-each-loop-causes-fatal-error/66047406#660474)

Both of them are similar to this tutorial of Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The current answer is already working for me, but if something comes up I'll try out yours.