# Toggle selection in a list - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, toggle

I hope I can explain my question clearly.

I want to select some courses from list via toggle but whatever I've tried it didn't work.

What am I supposed to do?

Thank you for your time.
Bests,
Murat

```
struct SubjectCardsView: View {
    // MARK: - Properties
    @State var courses: [Course] = Bundle.main.decode("courses.json")
    
    @State private var toggle: Bool = false
    
    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                
                ForEach(courses) { course in
                    Section(header: Text(course.title).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(.blue)) {
                        ForEach(course.courseName, id: \.name) { item  in
                            Toggle(isOn: $toggle, label: {
                                Text(item.name)
                            })
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Choose your subject", displayMode: .inline).font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Cancel")
            }), trailing: Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Save")
            }))
            
            
        } // NavigationView
    }
}
```

Course part!

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Course: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var subjectCount: String
    var courseName: [Content]
    var isToggled = false
    
    private var imageName: String
    var image: Image {
        Image(imageName)
    }

    enum LessonSegment: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case overview
        case resources

        var id: String { self.rawValue }
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case subjectCount
        case imageName
        case courseName
   
    }
}

struct Content: Codable {
    
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var content: String
    var assessment: String
    var notify: String
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `Course`?

Comment: Yes. I edited the original message.

Comment: So you want to toggle whether each `Content` is selected? Is there a certain property on `Content` that should respond to the toggle? Looks like you have a `isToggled` on `Course`, but your `Toggle` control is under a `ForEach` for `courseName` so it's a little unclear. Secondly, are you stuck with `Int` ids or can you use something more unique like UUIDs?

Comment: Each courseName has a toggle so I can understand which on is selected. After selection,  it will be saved and filtered in content view. I try to UUID and Int ids but they don't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `@State private var toggle: Bool = false` doesn't make sense. You have many courses, not a single course. Each course should have it's own toggle on/off, which is what you started to do with:

```
struct Course: Codable, Identifiable {
    var isToggled = false /// here!

    ...
}
```

To use this, you can reference each `course`'s `isToggled` inside the ForEach, like this:

```
ForEach(courses) { course in

    Section(header: Text(course.title).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(.blue)) {
        ForEach(course.courseName, id: \.name) { item  in

            ///          here!
            Toggle(isOn: course.isToggled, label: {
                Text(item.name)
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

However, this won't work. `course.isToggled` is a `Bool`, not a `Binding<Bool>`, which the Toggle expects.

Where can you get `Binding<Bool>`? From the `@State var courses: [Course]`, of course! <sub>sorry for pun</sub>

---

#### The `Binding<>` part comes from the `@State` declaration.

Properties that are marked with `@State`, like your `@State var courses: [Course]`, include a [`projectedValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/projectedvalue) that has the `Binding<>` type.

You can access the `projectedValue` by adding a `$` to the property. So, if you write `$courses`, that will have type `Binding<[Course]>`.

[image: Xcode autocompletion for $courses]

But, your toggle expects `Binding<Bool>`, not `Binding<[Course]>`.

[image: Toggle(isOn: Binding, label: { Text("A cool toggle") })]

#### This is where the `Bool` part comes in.

You will need to replace the Binding's value, `[Course]`, with a `Bool`. Well, we had a `Bool` before, right?

```
struct Course: Codable, Identifiable {
    var isToggled = false /// this is a Bool!
```

Each course has a `isToggled`, which is a `Bool`. From earlier on in this answer, we got this inside the `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(courses) { course in

    ...

    ///          getting the Bool, which unfortunately doesn't work (yet)
    Toggle(isOn: course.isToggled, label: {
```

... We need to somehow combine the `Binding<>` with the `Bool`. This means that we must

- reference `$courses` (to get the `Binding<>`)
- get each courses' `isToggled`

And... tada!

```
$courses[index].isToggled /// has type Binding<Bool>
```

To get `index`, we'll need to loop over [`courses.indices`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/indices) instead of directly looping over `courses`.

```
ForEach(courses.indices) { index in

    ...

    ///          this works! 
    Toggle(isOn: $courses[index].isToggled, label: {
```

Then, just replace every occurrence of `course` in your old code's `ForEach` with **`courses[index]`**. Here's the full working example:

```
ForEach(courses.indices) { index in
    Section(header: Text(courses[index].title).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(.blue)) {
        ForEach(courses[index].courseName, id: \.name) { item  in

            /// $courses[index].isToggled is a Binding<Bool>
            Toggle(isOn: $courses[index].isToggled, label: {
                Text(item.name)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

As a convenience so you don't have to do `courses[index]` every time you want the current `course`, you can use `Array(zip` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66944424/14351818) to loop over a `(Int, Course)`. This also assigns a unique `id` for every `Section` inside the loop, so any transitions you add will work out smoothly.

```
ForEach(Array(zip(courses.indices, courses)), id: \.1.id) { (index, course) in

    Section(header: Text(course.title).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(.blue)) {
        ForEach(course.courseName, id: \.name) { item  in

            Toggle(isOn: $courses[index].isToggled, label: {
                Text(item.name)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Well `(Int, Course)` is actually `(Range<Array<Course>.Index>.Element, Course)` but that's pretty much the same thing.</sup>

Final result:

[image: Toggles inside each row of the ForEach working]

---

Edit for `isToggled` inside `Content`, not `Course`:

```
ForEach(Array(zip(courses.indices, courses)), id: \.1.id) { (index, course) in
    Section(header: Text(course.title).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(.blue)) {
        ForEach(Array(zip(course.courseName.indices, course.courseName)), id: \.1.id) { (itemIndex, item) in

            ///          here!
            Toggle(isOn: $courses[index].courseName[itemIndex].isToggled, label: {
                Text(item.name)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and your answer. It works. Almost two day, I've worked on it. I learned something today. : )

Comment: @muradi I added some extra clarification to my answer :)

Comment: Thank you again. I want to ask one more question. Each course has two or more courseNames and toggle is working as a block again.  Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @muradi sure, what is it?

Comment: I'm trying to upload the screen sharing. [link](https://imgur.com/o0wXuHd)

Comment: @muradi, check what [jnpdx said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67064272/toggle-selection-in-a-list-swiftui/67064699#comment118542768_67064272). Move the `isToggled` from `Course` into `Content`.

Comment: @muradi np, after you move `isToggled`, use the code in my edited answer