# SwiftUI: String property of an object is not displaying in Text, and how would you edit a string in an object?

Tags: arrays, swift, object, swiftui

I am very new to programming in Swift. So I'm trying to come up with a time management program. I have posted some code that have been derived from my project that is a work in progress, and I'm trying to troubleshoot some issues that I'm having that come from my lack of knowledge regarding Swift and SwiftUI. I would like to ask two questions here, but if you only have the answer to just one of them, I would greatly appreciate it.

So in my ContentView, I'm trying to display the taskName of the object with ID 0 using a Text in a VStack -- however, it is not displaying, and I'm not sure of the reason why. I can display the taskLength by putting it inside the String method, but taskName is not coming up when I attempt to display it.

Also I'm attempting to change the taskName of Task(id: 0) that is being passed into display2 directly from the display2, but I'm not sure if the taskName of Task(id: 0) is actually being changed, or it's only the taskName of @State var task:Task in display2 that is being changed -- based on my intuitions, I would think the latter case is actually happening. In that case, is there a way to directly edit the taskName of Task(id: 0) from display2?

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

struct Task: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var taskName: String = ""
    var taskLength: Int = 0
    var isBreak : Bool = false
}

class ModelData : ObservableObject{
    @Published var tasks: [Task] = [
        Task(id: 0,taskName: "Test", taskLength: 34, isBreak: false),
        Task(id: 1,taskName: "Math", taskLength: 30, isBreak: false),
        Task(id: 2,taskName: "Science", taskLength: 40, isBreak: false)
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(Task(id: 0).taskName)
            display2(task:Task(id: 0))
        }
    }
}

struct display2: View{
    @State var task:Task
    var body: some View {
        TextField("New task",text: $task.taskName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Text(Task(id: 0).taskName)
```

Here, you're creating a *new* `Task`, with an `id` of 0. This is **not** the first task inside your `ModelData`'s `tasks` array.

Instead, reference the first task via subscript `[]`:

```
Text(modelData.tasks[ /* index of task */ ].taskName)
```

Normally you can just put `0` here to get the first `Task`. However, you said you actually want the `Task` *with an `id` of `0`*. You can do this via [`firstIndex(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(
                modelData.tasks[getTaskIndexFrom(id: 0)] /// access 
                    .taskName
            )
            
            Display2( /// see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064699/14351818
                task: $modelData.tasks[getTaskIndexFrom(id: 0)]
            )
        }
    }
    func getTaskIndexFrom(id: Int) -> Int {
        
        /// get first index of a task with the specified `id`
        if let firstIndex = modelData.tasks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == 0 }) {
            return firstIndex
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}

struct Display2: View{
    @Binding var task: Task /// need a Binding here
    var body: some View {
        TextField("New task", text: $task.taskName)
    }
}
```

Ok, your second question:

> In that case, is there a way to directly edit the taskName of Task(id: 0) from display2?

Yep! Just use `@Binding` on `Display2`'s `task`. This way, all changes will be synced back to your `modelData`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- it is very detailed. But I tried copying the code you provided, and I'm getting a fatal error. Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ModelData found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ModelData may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

Comment: Make sure that inside `YourApp.swift`, you do `ContentView().environmentObject(ModelData())` or similar. This is also mentioned in [Taeeun Kim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68897972/14351818).

Comment: Yeah, I did that, and the problem still persists. It's fine; in my main program I implemented the syntax for accessing the first task that you gave me and used @Binding, and it worked out! So in the end, your solution worked for me -- thank you so much.

Comment: @swiftNewb ah ok, nice! If it worked can you press the green checkmark to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In ContentView you used just Task(), but you have to use `modelData` for `@Published var tasks` in ModelData.

---

`Task(id: 0).taskName` -> `modelData.tasks[1].taskName`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(modelData.tasks[1].taskName)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            display2(task:Task(id: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also, as long as you use `@EnvironmentObject`, you need to add `.environmentObject` to the main as well.
(The code below is an example of the SwiftUI life cycle)

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ReplyToStackoverflowApp: App {
    var modelData: ModelData = ModelData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(modelData)
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks so much! I am grateful for your answer.